# How can I edit the way the images are displayed?

Tags: media

For a  course in university , we have to make a website in Drupal. The problem is, we don't know a lot of HTML and CSS (except for the information we can find on internet). So I don't really know how to solve my problem.

Have a look at this image:

[image]

You can see all the images are shown underneath each other. I want them in a horizontal line, like some kind of grid (4 images next to each other and then a new row with another 4 images ).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It's not about Drupal itself. You need some css knowledge.

Install [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) (for firefox) first and then check your images' class via firebug.

Then add something like that to your css file:

```
.my-image { float: left; width: 25% }
```

If you don't know how to do these, learn a little css and html to survive.